# Laravel API with Google Analytics

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, google-analytics

I made a REST API with Laravel, basically I get they route pass the route to the controller and from the controller I get the data and return a json formatted response, I was wondering If there is any way to add Google Analytics tracking to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet seems to be the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Also, since Laravel has the ability to run packages, it appears someone has already created an appropriate package for Laravel:

https://github.com/irazasyed/laravel-gamp

Note - I have not tried this package so I can't say whether it will save time over implementing the calls directly according to the GAMP docs.

Comment: You're welcome.  I took a look at its documentation and it looks pretty simple to use.  Hope it does the trick!

Comment: Glad to hear!  Good luck to you.